# How is the best way to play an MP3 file with a start time and end time in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project that requires sound snippets to be played from MP3 files in a playlist.  The files are full songs.

I have tried pygame mixer and I can pass the start time of the file, but I cannot pass the end time that I want the music to stop, or be able to fade-in and fade out the current snippet.

I have looked at the vlc and ffmpeg libraries, but I do not see the functionality I am looking for.

I'm hoping someone may be aware of a library out there that may be able to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do exactly what I wanted to do!

In the spirit of helping others I am posting an answer to my own question.

My development environment:

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6
Python 3.7.4
PyAudio 0.2.11
PyDub 0.23.1

Here it is in it's most rudimentary form:

```
import pyaudio
from pydub import AudioSegment

# Assign a mp3 source file to the PyDub Audiosegment
mp3 = AudioSegment.from_mp3("path_to_your_mp3_file")

# Specify starting and ending offsets from the beginning of the stream
# then apply a fadein and fadeout.  All values are  in millisecond (seconds * 1000).

mp3 = mp3[int(43000):int(58000)].fade_in(2000).fade_out(2000)

# In the above example the music will start 43 seconds into the track with a 2 second
# fade-in, and only play for 15 seconds with a 2 second fade-out.  If you don't need
# these features, just comment out the line and the full mp3 will play.

# Assign the PyAudio player
player = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Create the stream from the chosen mp3 file
stream = player.open(format = player.get_format_from_width(mp3.sample_width),
        channels = mp3.channels,
        rate = mp3.frame_rate,
        output = True)

data = mp3.raw_data

while data:
    stream.write(data)
    data=0

stream.close()
player.terminate()
```

It isn't in the example above, but there is a way to process the stream and increase/decrease/mute the volume of the music.

One other thing that could be done is to set up a thread to pause the processing (writing) of the stream, which would emulate a pause button in a player.